# Tabcontrol Tab ItemDatabinding

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have a tab control...To which tab items are added dynamically.Each tab item contains a data grid
My tab conrtol is

```
 <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Name="tabControl"  ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}" >
            </TabControl>
```

the template...

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGrid>
     </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>




public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            NewCmnd = new RelayCommand(NewCommandExecute, NewCommandCanExecute);
            TabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
            GridSource = new DataTable();
            GridSource.Columns.Add("Column1");
            GridSource.Columns.Add("Column2");
            GridSource.Columns.Add("Column3");
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public DataTable GridSource
        {
            get
            {
                return dt;
            }
            set
            {
                dt = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GridSource"));
            }
        }
```

And iam adding tab items as

```
TabItems.Add(new TabItem());
            DataRow dr = GridSource.NewRow();
            dr["Column1"] = "abc";
            dr["Column2"] = "abc";
            dr["Column3"] = "abc";
        GridSource.Rows.Add(dr);
```

but my UI is not updated..Can any one tell me the posssible reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure DataTable implements the necessary notification mechanism to update the UI. From your code, I can suggest a simple alternative of creating a DataTable and adding data to it followed by setting the property "GridSource" .

As per your existing code property changed is fired when you create a new DataTable and set it to "GridSource" at this time the DataTable is empty and UI is rendered accordingly.

**UPDATE**

my xaml code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid MinHeight="100">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Content="Add Row" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Add TabItem" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}" MinHeight="100"></TabControl>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

this is my code behind, although not following MVVM

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<TabItemContainer> tabItems;


    public ObservableCollection<TabItemContainer> TabItems
    {
        get { return tabItems; }
        set
        {
            tabItems = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItemContainer>();
        TabItemContainer container = new TabItemContainer();
        TabItems.Add(container);

        DataTable table = container.Data;


        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row["Name"] = "ABC";
        row["Amount"] = 10;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        container.Data = table;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItemContainer container = ((Button)sender).DataContext as TabItemContainer;
        DataRow row = container.Data.NewRow();
        row["Name"] = "ABC";
        row["Amount"] = 10;
        container.Data.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItems.Add(new TabItemContainer());
    }


}

public class TabItemContainer
{
    private DataTable data;

    public DataTable Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                data = new DataTable();
                data.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                data.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));
            }
            return data;
        }
        set
        {
            data = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So will not the property changed fire at the line of code " GridSource.Rows.Add(dr);" ???

Comment: Not unless DataTable.Row provides the facility. I'm sure your TabItems must be firing it as its an ObsservableCollection.

Comment: You can also try `GridSource = GridSource` after adding the rows.

Comment: Or else can you suggest some other method?to display it in a grid pattern?

Comment: I tried the thing you were trying and after a few hits i got it working. Although when we add the first tab item, it is not selected by default and hence the content area appears blank. I'll update my answer to show my code..

Comment: Thank you so much for the update and the answer. I will try out it in my MVVM pattern

Comment: I tried out your sample.. It is working nice..  i hope I can integrate it to the MVVM pattern.Once again thanks for the update..